# The preserve 3d property isn't working with the translate z

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .card {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  .card-content {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2em;
    background-color: pink;
    /* display: grid;
            justify-items: center;
            align-items: center; */
    transition: transform 3s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  
  .card:hover .card-content {
    transform: rotateY(.5turn);
  }
  
  .front-card,
  .back-card {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  .back-card {
    transform: rotateY(.5turn);
  }
  
  .title {
    transform: translateZ(500px);
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="front-card">
        <h2 class="title">THE FAIR</h2>
        <p>the trade fair </p>
      </div>


      <div class="back-card">
        <p class="text">
          random lorem ipsum text is what i'm gonna put right here
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So... as you can see right now the title is supposed to come forward, I've added the preserve-3d and it ain't still working.
Please i want the title to come forward using the transform : translateZ;.
The preserve-3d isn't working, the translate isn't making the title to come forward when it rotates.

Comment: `backface-visibility: hidden` on the font-card and back-card?

Comment: I know, I want the text to like come out, to be kinda 3d.

Comment: you need to add perspective, preserve-3d is not enough

Comment: i added preserve-3d to the front and back card and also the card content

Answer (score 0):

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .card {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  .card-content {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2em;
    background-color: pink;
    /* display: grid;
            justify-items: center;
            align-items: center; */
    transition: transform 3s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  
  .card:hover .card-content {
    transform: rotateY(.5turn);
  }
  
  .front-card,
  .back-card {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  .back-card {
    transform: rotateY(.5turn);
  }
  
  .title {
    transform: translateZ(500px);
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="front-card">
        <h2 class="title">THE FAIR</h2>
        <p>the trade fair </p>
      </div>


      <div class="back-card">
        <p class="text">
          random lorem ipsum text is what i'm gonna put right here
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

To solve this, I had to add transform:perspective-3d; to the card-content and the card-front and back-card.